# Once Radar chart is generated, it leaves a huge space between legend and the grapgh

Tags: javascript, charts

When I generated my Radar chart, it leaves some space between Legend and the grapgh. Any idea why this is happening? Thanks[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found that it's happening only when you have a lengthy labels. Setting a max-height fixed my issue

```
canvas {
  max-height: 400px;
}
```